# In graalvm, how to load tinylog.properties with native-image?

Tags: graalvm-native-image, tinylog

I use graalvm to build a jar with tinylog and work very good!
But when I use native-image build a exe,tinylog only work with default setting.
what can I do let tinylog can load my tinylog.properties with native-image?
please~ thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @Martin
I try to move
src\main\resources\tinylog.properties
to
src\main\resources\META-INF\native-image\tinylog.properties

regenerate properties with native-image-agent
and rebuild native-image.
Than it can load properties!
thank !

Answer (score 0):

On GitHub, you can find a minimal example project for using tinylog 2 in a native image build: https://github.com/tinylog-org/tinylog-graal-example

You need a custom Gradle task for generating the configuration for the native image (see [tinylog-graal-example/blob/v2/build.gradle](https://github.com/tinylog-org/tinylog-graal-example/blob/v2/build.gradle)).

```
task generateConfiguration(type: Exec) {
    group = "graal"
    description = "Run application to generate the configuration for native image generation"
    dependsOn jar, extractGraalTooling
    commandLine project.gradle.gradleUserHomeDir.toPath().resolve("caches/com.palantir.graal/$graalVmVersion/graalvm-ce-$graalVmVersion/bin/java"), "-agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=" + project.buildDir.toPath().resolve("resources/main/META-INF/native-image"), "-cp", sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.getAsPath(), javaMainClass

    doFirst {
        mkdir project.buildDir.toPath().resolve("resources/main/META-INF/native-image")
    }
}
```

Afterwards, you can run `./gradlew generateConfiguration` before `./gradlew nativeImage` for generating always the correct configuration.

Comment: I forget say .I use maven ><

Comment: IDK how to convert to maven version. and I don't see any sample. sorry